# Using play-services-wallet in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, android, gradle, intellij-idea, google-play-services

I'm trying to create a library that will use Google's play-services-wallet API. I've added it as a dependency in Gradle and it looks like the library is being added to the "External Libraries". However, I am not able to reference anything from play-services-wallet API. I have also tried to do this in Android Studio without any luck. I'm able to add the dependency to the main app module and it works fine but when I add it to the submodule within the same project I can't reference it. Is there something that I'm missing in the second module?

Comment: Do you see that library in module dependencies ("Project Structure | Modules - Dependencies") after Gradle refresh? Is it possible to provide sample project example?

Comment: Yes, I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong.  The library is an AAR file so I had to change some things in order for it to work. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was to fix it. The library is an AAR file so I had two options. Either extract the jar file from the Android archive and add that jar into my project or change the plugin of the module's build.gradle file from Java to Android library. So I went ahead and changed the module plugin to Android library.

I changed this

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

to this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

You also have to make a few changes to make sure that the module complies with the Android library plugin requirements. This fix is also good for anyone trying to use Google Play Services or any other Android archive in a java library.